# SQL sum values in columns for each row

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
column1 | column2 | column3
  1        3          4
  5        7          6
```

how do I sum the values of say, column 2 and 3, to return the sum?

The expected result is:

```
res
7
13
```

Comment: select (column2 + column3) as res from table

Comment: If those columns are NULLable you probably want to apply COALESCE: `coalesce(column2,0) + coalesce(column3,0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do maths within a select statement, so the following will work:

```
SELECT column2 + column3 AS res FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in postgresql.

```
  select sum(col2+col3) from (
  select col1, col2,col3,row_number() over() as rows from column_sum )  as foo 
  group by rows order by rows;
```

Comment: This is just a complicated way to express `col2+col3` :-)